# Glue Schema registry from java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to get all schema versions id from specific schema name in Glue Schema Registry in Scala but It throws an error:

```
val cred: AWSCredentialsProvider =new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicSessionCredentials("***", "***", ""))
val schemas = AWSSchemasClient
  .builder()
  .withCredentials(cred)
  .build()
val request = new ListSchemasRequest()
request.setRegistryName("registry")
request.setSchemaNamePrefix("schema")
schemas.listSchemas(request).toString
```

Error:

```
com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonErrorShapeMetadata.withExceptionUnmarshaller(Lcom/amazonaws/transform/JsonErrorUnmarshaller;)Lcom/amazonaws/protocol/json/JsonErrorShapeMetadata;
```

Dependencies are

```
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.12.93" % Compile,
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.12.93" % Compile,
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the error, first using aws java sdk v2:

```
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "sdk-core" % "2.17.61" % Compile,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "aws-sdk-java" % "2.17.61" % Compile,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "aws-json-protocol" % "2.17.61" % Compile
```

Then with this code I get the schemas:

```
val cred: AwsCredentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName("profile").build()
val glueClient = GlueClient.builder().credentialsProvider(cred).build()    

val schemaId = SchemaId.builder().registryName("registry").schemaName("schema").build()
    val schemaVersionsRequest = ListSchemaVersionsRequest.builder().schemaId(schemaId).build()
    val list = glueClient.listSchemaVersions(schemaVersionsRequest)
    list.schemas().forEach(v=> {
        val schemaVersionNumber=SchemaVersionNumber.builder().versionNumber($v).build()
    val getSchemaVersion= GetSchemaVersionRequest.builder().schemaVersionNumber(schemaVersionNumber).schemaId(schemaId).build()
    val schemaVer=glueClient.getSchemaVersion(getSchemaVersion)
    println(schemaVer.toString)
    })
```